# Getting only 1 radio button to be saved instead of 2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In my page I can have multiple `addresses`, but the `user` can only select one `address`.

The problem I'm having is that both my radio buttons are being saved instead of just one.

So if the user has 2 `addresses` then only one should have `selected = 1` and the other address should be `selected = 0`, but at the moment both `address = 1`.

I haven't been able to only have 1 `address` selected and saved as such in the database. I know that I'm passing the `ID` of the selected radio button through, but I was hoping to have this happen.

E.G: When the user saves their first address that is then saved as their selected address `(selected = 1)` and any other addresses they add after that will be `(selected = 0)`.

If they change their mind and want their second address to be the one they use then the select it and that will then become like this, address 1 `(selected = 0)` and address 2 will become `(selected = 1)`.

I hope this made sense. If it didn't please let me know.

My form

```
@foreach($addresses as $address)
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <form id="address-radio" action="{{ route('account.post.addresses.radio', $address->id) }}" method="post">
            @csrf
            <div class="form-check">
                <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="address_option" id="address_{{ $address->id }}" {!! $address->selected == '1' ? 'checked' : '' !!}>
                <label for="address_{{ $address->id }}" class="form-check->label">
                    @if(!empty($address->complex))
                        {{ $address->complex }} <br>
                    @endif
                    {{ $address->address }} <br>
                    {{ $address->suburb }} <br>
                    {{ $address->city }} <br>
                    {{ $address->province }} <br>
                    {{ $address->postal_code }} <br>
                </label>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
@endforeach

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input[type="radio"]').on('change', function(){
            $(this).closest("form").submit();
        })
    })
</script>
```

and this is my function

```
public function postAddressesRadio(Request $request, $id)
{
    $selected = Address::findOrFail($id);
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;

    $not_selected = $selected->where('id', '!=', $id)
                                ->where('user_id', $user_id)->get();

    foreach($not_selected as $selected)
    {
        $selected->selected = "0";
    }

    if($request->address_option == 'on'){
        $selected->selected = '1';
    }

    $selected->save();

    return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Address was updated');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I've managed to do it. I'm not sure if there is a better way but this works.

In my function I did

```
public function postAddressesRadio(Request $request, $id)
{
    $address = Address::findOrFail($id);
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;

    $addresses = Address::where('user_id', $user_id)->get();

    foreach($addresses as $address)
    {
        if($address->id == $id)
        {
            $address->selected = "1";
        }else{
            $address->selected = "0";
        }

        $address->save();
    }
```

Comment: Write this instead if "& else" `$address->selected =  ($address->id == $id)` also you can 2 queries instead of the loop, the first sets all addresses to 0 and the second updates the selected one, another solution will be is to change selected to a date and always get the max (and you only update the selected address column)